# git filter-branch remove folder failed

Tags: git

I want to remove a folder from commits on my git repo, so I use this commend:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf folder' HEAD
git push origin master --force
```

But there is no any change on my git repo, those commits which contain the folder I want to delete still on git repo.

So I try it again, but there shows:

> .git-rewrite already exists please remove it

I don't know what else can I do to remove it from all commits which contain the folder on git repo permanently.

Comment: Deleting a file in a particular commit will not necessarily remove the file from the repository since that file will still exist in older commits.

Comment: Does that means there is no way to delete a folder from older commits? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Maybe I should just delete those older commits?.......lol

Comment: Why do you want to retroactively remove the folder?  One reason you might want to do this if that folder contains some massive files which are no longer used and are wasting space.

Comment: From what I can tell, if you really want to go back in history and remove te folder then you will have to rewrite history.

Comment: Isn't "git filter-branch" a way to rewrite history?

Comment: Those folder contains sensitive files but I didn't notice and push to git repo before I found it recently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to remove a file or directory completely from a git repository you must ensure that it is not referenced anymore.

In git a file (or blob object) is referenced by a tree object which is referenced by either another tree object or a commit object. Commit objects are referenced by branches, tags, in the reflog and so on.

Some time ago I had to completely remove a folder from a project and wrote a blog about it. So I don't want to repeat myself here. Just take a look at [Remove directories and files permanently from git](http://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2014/07/17/remove-directories-and-files-permanently-from-git/) page.

I also wrote a swing application that uses the `jgit` library to to this. Just try [GitDirStat](https://github.com/link-intersystems/GitDirStat). Making a copy of your current repo before is always a good choice.

> .git-rewrite already exists please remove it

Just do what the message says. Remove `.git-rewrite`.

PS: You don't have to use a `--tree-filter` an index filter will do it faster ;) Then you must use `git rm -rf --cached`.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: The operations that are presented below will override your git history. Be careful what you're doing and backup your repo if you're not sure what you're doing.

---

#### Git

After you removed the folder via `filter-branch`, like:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf folder' HEAD
```

and you pushed your changes to the repository (`git push origin master --force`), the objects needs to be dereferenced and garbage collected.

To check what's pointing (tags or branches) to the removed objects, check the following command:

```
git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original
```

Then to deference you need to expire reflog (default is 90 days) and force garbage collection, e.g.

```
git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

then push all your branches and tags to the remote:

```
git push origin --force --all
git push origin --force --tags
```

Source: [Permanently remove files and folders from Git repo](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-git-repo)

---

#### Bfg

Alternatively to remove specific files or folders completely, you can use [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). For example:

```
$ bfg --delete-folders folder --no-blob-protection my-repo.git
```

For further details, please follow above link or [*Advanced Git / Remove sensitive data*](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) GitHub page.

Answer (score 1):

I just did

```
rm -rf .git-rewrite
```

and it worked!!